# React-native axios with ColdFusion component

Tags: react-native, coldfusion, axios

I'm trying to send a get request from react native, using axios, to my coldfusion component.

My coldfusion component:

```
component displayName="react" {

remote any function ajaxLogin(data) returnformat="JSON"{
    data = deserializeJSON(arguments.data);
    return serializeJSON(login(data));
}

private any function login(data){
    loginQuery = new query();
    loginQuery.setDatasource("ds");
    loginQuery.setName("loginQuery");
    loginQuery.addParam(name="UserEmail",       value="#arguments.data.userEmail#",     cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
    loginQuery.addParam(name="UserPW",      value="#arguments.data.userPassword#",      cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
    result = loginQuery.execute(sql="SELECT * FROM Users Where UserEmail = :UserEmail AND UserPW = :UserPW");
    rs = result.getResult();
    if(rs.recordCount == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return rs.UserID;
    }
}
```

}

My react-native dispatch action:

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  // login
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'TEST' });
    axios.get('https://myserver.com/components/reactNative/react.cfc?method=ajaxLogin', {
      params: {
        userEmail: email,
        userPassword: password
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
};
```

It is returning an error from the catch:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

I am new with axios and react-native. Am I using axios wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should look in the browser to see what is being requested

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Use the react-native-debugger https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Answer (score 3):

Status code 500 is a server-side error so you're likely getting a Coldfusion error, check your ColdFusion logs.

Also as you're calling this as a GETrequest you can just open the URL in a browser tab and see if you get any errors dumped to the page (in a development environment)

`https://myserver.com/components/reactNative/react.cfc?method=ajaxLogin&userEmail=email&userPassword=password`

If this is production then you should see errors in your error logs (somewhere like `/var/www/opt/coldfusion_11/cfusion/logs` on linux)